# Xamarin Forms: add a new class project and a lot of predefined error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have my Xamarin project and it's perfectly working with some other class projects. I've created the initial solution with Visual Studio. Now I added a new class project in Xamarin Studio for Mac like

[image: Xamarin Studio > Add new Project]

Now I don't know for what reason, all predefined type don't exist like in the following picture (and an sample text).

> /path of my project/CSC: Error CS0518: The predefined type
>   `System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   (CS0518)

[image: Screenshot with errors]

I checked the version of .NET and it's the same of others (PCL 4.5 - Profile 111). tried to update Xamarin.Forms without success.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you restore all packages? Maybe your are not authenticated to xamarin and some packages didn't get restored!

Comment: Only for this project? Maybe the problem is I can't create a class project if other projects are created on Visual Studio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem opening the project files `csproj` with an editor. There I discovered a tag called `TargetFrameworkProfile` and I copied the same profile from another project.

An interesting thing is Xamarin Studio I can see the project in the tree but if I open the folder on the file system, the new project I created was under another project folder: I'm use I created the new one to right-click on the main solution.

Thank you guys for your suggestions.